Barrel adjuster built into Kona Rove frame
My Kona Rove ST (2020) frame has a single barrel adjuster integrated with the frame. It's at the front of the bike near the head tube located on the downtube on the left/non-drive side. I'm trying to figure out when or if I might ever use this component. When I bought my Kona Rove from my Local Bike Shop nothing was routed through the adjuster.

Kona's product photo also shows nothing routed through the adjuster and I'm failing to find any photos online where anyone uses this barrel adjuster.

When I look at the Park Tool video on "How to Size and Install Shift Cable Housing", the section regarding "segmented housing" illustrates a frame with "housing stops". In this scenario some of the shift cable is exposed, and shift cable housing near the headset stops at one housing stop, and there's another housing stop near the rear derailleur.

My frame has no housing stop near the rear derailleur unless I'm totally missing it.
Is my barrel adjuster for segmented shift cable routing? If so, shouldn't there be a matching barrel adjuster/housing stop at the rear end of the bike? Even if there was another housing stop at the rear I thought it seemed odd that the shift cable would need to run from the non-drive side to the drive-side. Although this bike was marketed as a 1x drivetrain maybe this component is here for the possibility of a front derailleur?

Presuming your bike has a hydraulic rear brake, and the cable to the rear derailleur is on the other side of the frame ?

I have the stock TRP Spyre C mechanical disk brakes that came standard with this model. That cable for the rear brakes runs along the non-drive side and the rear derailleur cable runs along the drive side.

My guess is that the Kona Rove ST and the Swift Rove

used the same frame. The two frames have exactly the same dimensions.
The Swift has a front derailleur that used the integrated barrel adjuster. The Rove ST can also be purchased as a frame and the integrated barrel adjuster provides a handy way of having a front derailleur should it be desired.

OP could use the same stops for an externally-routed dropper post cable, no?   I can't think of a situation where it makes sense to cut them off, perhaps unscrew the adjuster barrel and spring, and store that away.

I just bought a 2024 Rove DL frame. That cable stop with the barrel adjuster is for a front derailleur. You can see it in use in this version of the Rove https://www.konaworld.com/en-ca/products/rove. You could unscrew the barrel adjustor and store it safely in a parts bin in case you might want to run a 2x in the future - that would keep it from getting corroded.
I believe the frame is designed to use a full housing for a mechanical rear brake, but I could be wrong. That's how I'm expecting to build mine up.
